# How to trigger two job from single job in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, build

I have one main Job on Jenkins.
I also created two jobs:

- One job for scm changes build
- One for Scheduled Build

In both job I gave the same configuration file as well as workspace.
I just give the name of job different.

Now from the main job through script I'm triggering SCM changes build which is success.
Again from the main job through script I am triggering Scheduled Build which is success.

When both trigger is started from main job, as same time that is SCM changes and scheduled build.

I am getting error due to in both job I gave the same workspace.

How to decide through script from main job when Scheduled build is over then start SCM change build?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trigger the SCM change build from the scheduled build instead of the main job, using the "Trigger / call builds on other projects" option in the main job's build steps.

[image]

Comment: when i am using  "Trigger / call builds on other projects" option in the main job's build steps i am getting just below "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds".Should i tick in field "Block until the triggered projects finish their builds"?

Comment: It depends if you want builds of the main job to be marked as complete before the triggered builds have completed.

Comment: can i solve this problem also by using build blocker plugin?

Comment: It's provided by this plugin: https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin